# Allow remote users to control this Mac

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extensions

Everytime I restart my Mac, I get following message on my screen:

[image: org.chromium.chromoting.me2me.sh]

I must have deleted `org.chromium.chromoting.me2me.sh` by accident (as it was there before)

Please advise.

Comment: Did you check System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items tab to see if CRD starts up from there? Do you actually want to use CRD, or just want to stop this behavior?

Comment: @IconDaemon I checked and CRD is not there and yes I'd like to use CRD)